# How to use different versions of QtCreator?

Tags: qt-creator

I know there is usually no point to have older IDE versions, but in my team we had issues with our environment and cmake architecture when we tried to upgrade from 3.6 to 4.0 so we stepped back.

Now I want to test the new version of QtCreator to see if it's working fine, but without removing my current version because I could need it to work on urgent tasks.

The Qt install folder allows to have different Qt versions but there is only one *Tools* folder for QtCreator. Is there any simple way to add another version ? Or if I just install it somewhere else by myself, can it mess up my configuration and Qt installation ?
(I'm on windows btw)

Thx !

Comment: What is wrong with cmake support in 4.0? IMHO that took a huge step forward in 4.0. I'd really like to know so I can improve it:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab the Qt Creator stand-alone package and install that somewhere.

Do make sure to keep you user settings though, as Creator will upgrade those and your older version will not be able to read all of them afterwards. You can either:

- Make a copy of (%APPDATA%/.../QtProject or ~/.config/QtProject IIRC) of your existing settings
- Specify a different setting folder for QT Creator by starting the new Creator with the option: `-settingspath /some/dir`.